# How to find number of Reference Planes passing through a selected wall.

Tags: revit-api, revit

I need to find out the number of Reference planes and their names which are passing through a selected wall. I can get all the reference planes for a particular document but how shall I do this for a particular wall.

You help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ElementIntersectFilter` doesn't work for your needs, you'll have to extract the geometry of the wall and reference plane and work with those directly.

Intersecting the reference planes with the wall solids can work, but there's a simpler answer that will work, if I understand your question correctly.  I'm assuming you only want the walls where the green line of the ref plane intersects, rather than treating the reference plane object as an infinite geometric plane.  In the screenshot below, I assume you want to find the checkmarks, but not the red X's.  [image: revit screenshot] I'm also assuming you're looking at this as a plan exercise, and not specifically setting the vertical extents of the reference plane  (this is just based on how I've seen most people use Revit).  The following function takes as inputs a single wall and a list of ref planes (you mentioned you already have the collection of all ref planes) and will return a list of ref planes which intersect the wall.

```
public static List<ReferencePlane> getRefPlanesIntersectingWall( Wall wal, List<ReferencePlane> refPlanesIn)
    {
        //simplify this to a 2D problem, using the location curve of the wall

        List<ReferencePlane> refPlanesOut = new List<ReferencePlane>();
        LocationCurve wallLocation = wal.Location as LocationCurve;
        Curve wallCurve = wallLocation.Curve;
        Double wallZ = wallLocation.Curve.GetEndPoint(0).Z;

        foreach (ReferencePlane rp in refPlanesIn)
        {
            XYZ startPt = new XYZ(rp.BubbleEnd.X, rp.BubbleEnd.Y, wallZ);
            XYZ endPt = new XYZ(rp.FreeEnd.X, rp.FreeEnd.Y, wallZ);
            Line rpLine = Line.CreateBound(startPt, endPt);
            SetComparisonResult test = wallCurve.Intersect(rpLine);

            if (test == SetComparisonResult.Overlap || 
                test == SetComparisonResult.Subset ||
                test == SetComparisonResult.Superset ||
                test == SetComparisonResult.Equal  )
            {
                refPlanesOut.Add(rp);
            }
        }
        return refPlanesOut;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying the built-in `ElementIntersectFilter`.  The documentation has a nice example, replace "`FamilyInstance`" with "`referencePlane`" and that may do it.

http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/19276b94-fa39-64bb-bfb8-c16967c83485.htm

If that doesn't work, you'll need to extract the solid of the wall and intersect with the reference plane.

Comment: The above din't work for me. I tried extracting the solid of the wall and tried to intersect with the reference plane. No luck in here as well.